# Typeahead blur event not fired on iPhone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iphone, angular-ui

I have a simple bootstrap [typeahed](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead) directives which works fine. 
But on an iPhone the drop down menu doesn't closed on blur (when I touch else where on my page).

It does works when I try on the typeahaed demo page on an iPhone.

Do I need to do anything special for the blur events to get fired when clicking on my body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix for my problem which solve the closing of the dropdown on iPhone and iPad.

I've just added on mobile devices the css rule:

```
body { cursor: pointer; }
```

That's it!